# PHP cURL One Liner?

Tags: php, curl, terminal

So im trying to execute a terminal cURL command within a PHP script

The command in question

```
curl -H "public-api-token: mykeyhere" -X PUT -d "urlToShorten=google.com" https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
```

The response is a JSON and is as follows

```
 {"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\/\/sh.st\/XXXX"}
```

I put it in my PHP script as follows, hoping it would add to a smaller and more effective code footprint

```
 $cmd='curl -H "public-api-token: mysecretkey" -X PUT -d "urlToShorten=google.com" https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url';
 exec($cmd,$result);
 print_r($result);
```

However the returned array is empty

The result is

```
 Array ( )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec() returns the last line of output, try using shell_exec().